# Killing async function calls in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to **kill an asynchronous function call** in node.js or do I have to call the function and then another one to **kill the whole process** after a specific amount of time?

Comment: You can use `return` within the function.

Comment: I know, but I'm talking about functions I didn't write. So I wanna start third party functions, and kill them if they run too long.

Comment: code code code? without code this cannot be answered

Comment: Not in any general way, no.  You only could if the asynchronous call returned an object that provided a means of canceling the operation it's tied to.

Comment: Node is single-threaded.  How are you going to check whether it has taken too long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, But check following code, you can get some idea to achieve the stuff.

```
var logrunningFunction = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Delayed");
    cb();
  }, 5000);

};


var cb = function(){
  console.log("long running function completed");
};
logrunningFunction(cb);

setTimeout(function(){
  cb = function(){
    console.log("Overwrite long running handler");
  };
},1000);
```